# Creating hierarchical commands using Python Click

Tags: python, python-click

Suppose I want to create a CLI that looks like this

```
cliName user create
cliName user update
```

How would I do this?

I've tried doing something like this -

```
@click.group()
def user():
   print("USER")
   pass

@user.command()
def create():
    click.echo("create user called")
```

when I run `cliName user create`, the print statements do not run. Nothing runs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import click


@click.group()
def cli(**kwargs):
    print(1)


@cli.group()
@click.option("--something")
@click.option("--else")
def what(**kwargs):
    print(2)


@what.command()
@click.option("--chaa")
def ever(**kwargs):
    print(3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()


# ./cli.py what ever
# 1
# 2
# 3
```